# Getting the id of the last record inserted for Postgresql SERIAL KEY with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am using SQLAlchemy without the ORM, i.e. using hand-crafted SQL statements to directly interact with the backend database. I am using PG as my backend database (psycopg2 as DB driver) in this instance - I don't know if that affects the answer.

I have statements like this,for brevity, assume that conn is a valid connection to the database:

```py
conn.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, country_id) VALUES ('Homer', 123)")
```

Assume also that the user table consists of the columns `(id [SERIAL PRIMARY KEY], name, country_id)`

How may I obtain the id of the new user, ideally, without hitting the database again?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: For `mysql` and `sqlalchemy`, use `result.lastrowid`.

I know the question is aimed for `postgresql`, Google don't, may be because of the title.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might be able to use the `RETURNING` clause of the [`INSERT` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) like this:

```
result = conn.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, country_id) VALUES ('Homer', 123)
                       RETURNING *")
```

If you only want the resulting `id`:

```
result = conn.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, country_id) VALUES ('Homer', 123)
                        RETURNING id")
[new_id] = result.fetchone()
```

Comment: Definitely what I needed. The returned object was a ResultProxy in both cases, so I had to modify the code a little (by calling fetchone()) to get it to work.

Comment: Alternatively, `user.insert().returning(user.c.id).values({'name': 'Homer', 'country_id': 123})`

Comment: This solution doesn't work with `sqlite`. It results in `sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: RETURNING is not supported by this dialect's statement compiler.`. The other solution (`lastrowid`) works in that case.

Comment: @PrahladYeri: This question is about Postgres, not SQLite.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I understand that, but the whole point of sqlalchemy is database abstraction, so I just noted that it may not be possible in this scenario (getting lastrowid).

Comment: I also had to fetchall() since returning object was <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x0000029C26D1BEF0>

Comment: To clarify the previous comments, if you modify your query to include a `RETURNING id` so you have something like this: `result_obj = conn.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, country_id) VALUES ('Homer', 123) RETURNING id")` then you can get the last inserted id by using `fetchone()` and getting items out of the tuple returned:  `last_inserted_id = result_obj.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: the connection closed automatics after insert, no fetchone or fetchall works any helpful idea to what I can do

Answer (score 33):

User [`lastrowid`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html?highlight=lastrowid#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.lastrowid)

```
result = conn.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, country_id) VALUES ('Homer', 123)")
result.lastrowid
```

Comment: Sorry i dont have pgsql at my desk i used mysql :)

Comment: More specifically, it doesn't work with tables with no oid, which is currently the default. And anyway it's often not the oid you are looking for: RETURNING is a way superior solution.

Answer (score 18):

Current SQLAlchemy [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key) suggests

`result.inserted_primary_key` should work!

Answer (score 11):

**Python + SQLAlchemy**

after commit, you get the primary_key column id (autoincremeted) updated in your object.

```
db.session.add(new_usr)
db.session.commit() #will insert the new_usr data into database AND retrieve id
idd = new_usr.usrID # usrID is the autoincremented primary_key column. 
return jsonify(idd),201 #usrID = 12, correct id from table User in Database.
```

Comment: For me this only works if my model class name is the same as the `__tablename__` - if they are different I get an error when trying to access `usrID`

Answer (score 9):

this question has been asked many times on stackoverflow and no answer I have seen is comprehensive. Googling 'sqlalchemy insert get id of new row' brings up a lot of them.

There are three levels to SQLAlchemy.
Top: the ORM.
Middle: Database abstraction (DBA) with Table classes etc.
Bottom: SQL using the text function.

To an OO programmer the ORM level looks natural, but to a database programmer it looks ugly and the ORM gets in the way. The DBA layer is an OK compromise. The SQL layer looks natural to database programmers and would look alien to an OO-only programmer.

Each level has it own syntax, similar but different enough to be frustrating. On top of this there is almost too much documentation online, very hard to find the answer.

I will describe how to get the inserted id AT THE SQL LAYER for the RDBMS I use.

```
Table: User(user_id integer primary autoincrement key, user_name string)
conn: Is a Connection obtained within SQLAlchemy to the DBMS you are using.


SQLite
======
insstmt = text(
    '''INSERT INTO user (user_name)
    VALUES (:usernm) ''' )
# Execute within a transaction (optional)
txn = conn.begin()
result = conn.execute(insstmt, usernm='Jane Doe')
# The id!
recid = result.lastrowid
txn.commit()


MS SQL Server
=============
insstmt = text(
    '''INSERT INTO user (user_name) 
    OUTPUT inserted.record_id
    VALUES (:usernm) ''' )
txn = conn.begin()
result = conn.execute(insstmt, usernm='Jane Doe')
# The id!
recid = result.fetchone()[0]
txn.commit()


MariaDB/MySQL
=============
insstmt = text(
    '''INSERT INTO user (user_name)
    VALUES (:usernm) ''' )
txn = conn.begin()
result = conn.execute(insstmt, usernm='Jane Doe')
# The id!
recid = conn.execute(text('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')).fetchone()[0]
txn.commit()


Postgres
========
insstmt = text(
    '''INSERT INTO user (user_name)
    VALUES (:usernm) 
    RETURNING user_id ''' )
txn = conn.begin()
result = conn.execute(insstmt, usernm='Jane Doe')
# The id!
recid = result.fetchone()[0]
txn.commit()
```

Comment: Interesting, but couldn't get it to work for sql server - using SA, and pymssql.

Comment: The connection string i use is ```mssql+pyodbc://MIPLTP041/dbname?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0```. Maybe pymssql uses one of the other protocols mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
result.inserted_primary_key
```

Worked for me.  The only thing to note is that this returns a list that contains that last_insert_id.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `fetchrow/fetch` to receive the `returning` object

```
insert_stmt = user.insert().values(name="homer", country_id="123").returning(user.c.id)

row_id = await conn.fetchrow(insert_stmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgress inserts from python code is simple to use "RETURNING" keyword with the "col_id" (name of the column which you want to get the last inserted row id) in insert statement at end

syntax -

```html
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 conn_string = "postgresql://USERNAME:PSWD@HOSTNAME/DATABASE_NAME"
 db = create_engine(conn_string)
 conn = db.connect()
 INSERT INTO emp_table (col_id, Name ,Age) 
        VALUES(3,'xyz',30) RETURNING  col_id;
 or
 (if col_id column is auto increment)
 insert_sql = (INSERT INTO emp_table (Name ,Age) 
        VALUES('xyz',30) RETURNING  col_id;)     
 result = conn.execute(insert_sql)
 [last_row_id] = result.fetchone()
 print(last_row_id)
 #output = 3
```

ex -
[image]